Create new sequence in a table
I need to create new sequence based on the SEQNO column below, I want the minimum SEQNO to always start with 1.  How do I do that?  I am not trying to alter the original table.  I am just trying to add a new column to the data I pull so it is easier for me to join with other tables.
Below are the examples from the table.  The column "Order" is the column I want to create when I pull the data based on column SEQNO.
ID SEQNO Order
N1    4    1
N1    7    2
N1    11   3
N2    3    1
N2    5    2

I didn't try anything because I don't know where to start.

Here's one way to do it: find ordinal number (the new sequence value) using row_number analytic function. Then merge it with the "original" table.
Before:
SQL> select * from test order by id, seqno;

ID      SEQNO    C_ORDER
-- ---------- ----------
N1          4
N1          7
N1         11
N2          3
N2          5

Set the new sequence:
SQL> merge into test a
  2  using (select b.id, b.seqno,
  3           row_number() over (partition by b.id order by b.seqno) c_order
  4         from test b
  5        ) x
  6  on (    a.id = x.id
  7      and a.seqno = x.seqno
  8     )
  9  when matched then update set
 10    a.c_order = x.c_order;

5 rows merged.

After:
SQL> select * from test order by id, seqno;

ID      SEQNO    C_ORDER
-- ---------- ----------
N1          4          1
N1          7          2
N1         11          3
N2          3          1
N2          5          2

SQL>

